# Object Mode shows mesh one way, and in Edit Mode another (pictures below)

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

All modifiers are applied.

[image]

[image]

It has probably something to do with decimate modifier. I reduced the vertices amount significantly to be VR friendly.

Could it be a bug or... am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: If modifiers were all applied then Decimate like any of them can't be the reason. Try pressing Alt+H in Edit mode and see if there's hidden geometry

Comment: @MrZak I am stupid..... yeah I forgot to check hidden objects. You saw nothing, Mr Zak!